# python convert date from string breaks when year is two digit

Tags: python, linux

i am trying to convert a date string to date format

```
>>> str = "04-18-2002 03:50PM"

>>> time.strptime(str, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M%p')
time.struct_time(tm_year=2002, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=18, tm_hour=3, tm_min=50, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=108, tm_isdst=-1)
```

however when the year is in two digit it breaks

```
>>> str = "04-18-02 03:50PM"
>>> time.strptime(str, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M%p')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 454, in _strptime_time
    return _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '04-18-02 03:50' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M'
```

any ideas??

Comment: BTW: m-d-Y notation is confusing. If using this anglo-american order, use / as separator. - is better used with Ymd notation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`%Y` in the format string denotes a four-digit year, see the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).  For a two-digit year, use `%y` instead.  To support both formats, first `try:` one of the formats, and catch the `ValueError` and try the other one.

Answer (score 3):

The correct format for a two-digit year is `%y` (lowercase `y`).

As a side note, please don't call the string variable `str` as it shadows the [builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str).